# RegEx match replace help

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a regex match and replace for an .htaccess file but I can't quite figure out the replace bit. I think I have the match part right, but maybe someone can help.

I have this url-
http://www.foo.com/MountainCommunities/Lifestyles/5/VacationHomeRentals.aspx

And I'm trying to turn it into this-
http://www.foo.com/mountain-lifestyle/Vacation-Home-Rentals.aspx

(MountainCommunities/Lifestyles)/\d/(.*)(.aspx)

and then I figured I would have a rewrite rule starting like this-

mountain-lifestyle/$2$3

but I need to take what is in $2 in this instance and rewrite it to place dashes between the words with capital letters. Now I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll have to do it in two bits... Take out $2, precede every capital (apart from the first) with a -, then use just append the result to http://www.foo.com/mountain-lifestyle/ with a .aspx on the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(([A-Z][a-z]+-)*)([A-Z][a-z]+)(([A-Z][a-z]+)+)(\.aspx)?$ /$1$3-$4 [N]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-z]+-)+[A-Z][a-z]+$ /$0.aspx [R=301]
```

Note that mod_rewrite uses an internal counter to detect and avoid infinit loops. So your URL may not contain too much words having to be converted (see [`MaxRedirects` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) for Apache < 2.1 and [`LimitInternalRecursion` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) for Apache ≥ 2.1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what your doing with the capital letters is possible with regex...

You would be better keeping the dashes in the URL and removing the .aspx

eg: http://www.foo.com/MountainCommunities/Lifestyles/5/Vacation-Home-Rentals

This would require the following rule:

```
^/MountainCommunities/Lifestyles/5/([^/]+)/\?([^/]+)   /mountain-lifestyle/$1.aspx?$2 [I]
```

This also takes into account any querystrings that are sent to the page.

BTW: How are you using .htaccess with IIS?

Comment: The Query String is not part of the URL path and thus cannot be checked within the RewriteRule directive.

Comment: @Gumbo: Of course it is. I'm current use ISAPI_rewrite to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression "([A-Z])" on the middle bit "VacationHome", replacing with the regex "-$1" - This will give you "-Vacation-Home-Rentals" - Then you can just chop off the first character, and stick the first part of the URL on the front, and .aspx on the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main regex has been written by others, but to match the request name to place dashes (assuming all the file names have a three-name camel cased representation ala 'VacationHomeRentals.aspx':

```
RewriteRule: ^/MountainCommunities/Lifestyles/\d+/([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)\.aspx$ /mountain-lifestyle/$1-$2-$3.aspx
```

This is a restricted version of @Gumbo's response, as I have not had a chance to test his recursion. The recursion technique is definitely the best and most usable for any scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite understand what you are trying to do.  Why can't you simply search for:

`http://www.foo.com/MountainCommunities/Lifestyles/5/VacationHomeRentals.aspx`

and replace it with:

`http://www.foo.com/mountain-lifestyle/Vacation-Home-Rentals.aspx` ?

Or is this a specific example of a patten you are trying to transform?